Large matrix in RcppArmaddilo - R package
I am developing an R package.
If the input of my function is large (approximately bigger than a couple of millions values), I have a message error:
`Mat::init(): requested size is too large; suggest to enable ARMA_64BIT_WORD`

I followed the comment in a previous post here, but unfortunately I am not able to compile the package once made the corrections. The corrections I made produced an error. I modified my cpp code as following:
#define R_NO_REMAP
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "ANN/ANN.h"        // ANN library header
#include "NN.h"             // ANN library header
#include <R.h>              // R header

#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD 1
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]] 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
FUNCTIONS.......

and the src/Makevars{.win} file as following
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I. -IANN -DRANN -DARMA_64BIT_WORD=1
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)  

Do you know how to solve this?
